# At what case/problem, Binary Insertion Sort would be faster than Insertion Sort?

Tags: sorting

We know Insertion Sort would be faster than Merge Sort and Quick Sort for nearly sorted data. What about Binary Insertion Sort? At what case is it better than Insertion Sort?

Also, is there a better solution than Binary Insertion Sort, for the problem is solves better than Insertion Sort?

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that binary insertion sort and insertion sort both do the same number of permutations between elements.

The main difference between the two is the number of comparisons. If comparisons are hard/time-consuming relatively to permutations, the binary insertion sort becomes interesting.

As an example, in my school, there is a limited number of students we can welcome, and we have to make some kind of ranking. We use binary insertion sort because the most time-consuming task (done by humans) is the comparisons of candidates.

With binary insertion sort, for an array of length $n$, the number of comparisons done is roughly:
$$\sum\limits_{i=2}^n\log_2(i) = \log_2(n!)$$
This is better than the $n\log_2 n$ comparisons done by merge-sort or the average $1.4n\log_2n$ comparisons done by quick-sort (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535540/exactly-how-many-comparisons-does-merge-sort-make)), or $2n\log_2n$ comparisons done by heap-sort. I am not sure there are better algorithms in number of comparisons.

Comment: Log n! = n (log n - 1), log_2 n! = (log_2 n - log_2 e) n.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion sort is faster than quicksort if o(log n) (that is little o, not Big O) items are in the wrong place. It will move o(n log n) items. This is slower than better methods which run in O(n) if the number of items in the wrong place is O(n / log n).

Binary insertion would use log n steps to find where to insert element k for a total of n log n. So when insertion sort is faster than quicksort, binary insertion isn’t.